# Error installing new RAM, getting 3 beeps (memory error) from motherboard

Tags: memory, hardware-failure

I have a hardware problem and hope this is the right place. I wanted to add some RAM and I got two kingston 2 GB sticks that I want to install, however, when I seat them and boot up the system I get 3 beeps (which indicates a memory error).

My motherboard is an [Intel DP45SG](http://ark.intel.com/products/34683/Intel-Desktop-Board-DP45SG), and the RAM I got is [Kingston KVR1333D3S8N9/2G](http://www.ec.kingston.com/ecom/configurator_new/partsinfo.asp?root=&LinkBack=&ktcpartno=KVR1333D3S8N9/2G) and as far as I can see they should be compatible.

I have 4 GB on my computer already (don't know what make) but I also tried installing the new sticks without the old ones so it's not compatibility issue with the old RAM...

Already tried to update BIOS and took out the CMOS battery to reset to default settings, didn't help. Also tried moving slots.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like of of your RAM modules is defective. Try them one by one to find out which is the culprit.

If one works without the other, you will have to return the module.

Comment: I already exchanged them at the store so I don't think the new RAM is faulty. The old ones also work when I don't put in the new ones so they are not faulty. only when I put in the new RAM (tried one at a time, and tried without the old RAM) I get the error...

Comment: What are the specifications of the old RAM modules?

Comment: They are Transcend DDR3 1333 Mhz 2GB each

Comment: Aside from all the new RAM modules being defective, I cannot think of anything else...

Comment: But do you think it's possible I got 2 sets of faulty modules? He even gave me the second set from a different pack

Comment: Likely? No. Possible? Yes.

Answer (score 2):

My friend, I have the same problem and I found the solution.

There are two kinds of RAM that look the same but if you look closely you will see the differences between them.

One of them is Kingston KVR1333D3S8N9/2G

The other is Kingston KVR1333D3N9/2G

If you compare them first one it has an "S8" in it

[KVR1333D3N9/2G 2GB 2Rx8 256M x 64-Bit PC3-10600 CL9 240-Pin DIMM](http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR1333D3N9_2G.pdf)

[KVR1333D3S8N9/2G 2GB 1Rx8 256M x 64-Bit PC3-10600 CL9 240-Pin DIMM](http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR1333D3S8N9_2G.pdf)

Be careful! The new RAM's barcode must be the same as old one.

I have detected it now and I am going to change it in a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some other incompatibility that isn't apparent.  Your motherboard is not listed on the [Kingston website](http://www.ec.kingston.com/ecom/configurator_new/models.asp?System=&Distributor=0&OriginalSysPN=&Manufacturer=&KTCPartNo=KVR1333D3S8N9/2G&root=&LinkBack=&submit1=Click%20Here) as being compatible with the memory you have purchased.  That doesn't necessarily mean it won't work, but Kingston doesn't officially support it for that board.

What they do recommend for you board is the [KVR1333D3S8N9H/2G](http://www.ec.kingston.com/ecom/configurator_new/modelsinfo.asp?SysID=45866&mfr=Intel&model=DP45SG%20Motherboard&search_type=&root=us&LinkBack=http://www.kingston.com&Sys=45866-Intel-DP45SG%20Motherboard&distributor=0&submit1=Search).  Not sure the difference between that model and the one you bought, though.